# WSO2ESB : behaving differently for different Content-Type

Tags: content-type, wso2-esb

I have a proxy flow like the below,

```
<proxy>
    <insequence>
         <header name="To"  expression="concat('http://localhost:8080/', substring-after(get-property('To'),'services/'))"/>
           <send>
              <endpoint>
                 <default/>
              </endpoint>
           </send>
    </insequence>
    </proxy>
```

when i send a request to wso2esb/services/my/sample/url,

if Content-Type is "text/xml", then the request is correctly forwarded to

```
  http://localhost:8080/my/sample/url  as expected
```

but if the Content-Type is "application/xml", then the request is getting forwarded to

```
 http://localhost:8080/my/sample/url/services/my/sample/url
```

My WSO2ESB version is Version 4.8.1

i don't know where i am getting it wrong..could anyone help me in providing solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

can you try adding the property `REST_URL_POSTFIX`

Have a look at https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/HTTP+Transport+Properties#HTTPTransportProperties-REST_URL_POSTFIXREST_URL_POSTFIX

Answer (score 0):

@Senduran: thanks for the answer.

I fixed the issue by doing a slight change

```
 <address uri="http://localhost:8080" format="rest"/>
```

i.e. it becomes

```
<proxy>
<insequence>
       <send>
          <endpoint>
              <address uri="http://localhost:8080" format="rest"/>
          </endpoint>
       </send>
</insequence>
</proxy>
```

I went with handling 'To' header after an suggestion from forum but it seems that it is not a legible way and it works for particular content type only

Comment: Sorry this didnt worked for SOAP messages..when the format of address endpoint is 'rest', it is not possible to send SOAP messages